# DB2 stored procedure FETCH doesn't move to the end of cursor

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC1()
    LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE EOF INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE SQLCODE INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE var_MYID INT;
    DECLARE PCURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT MYID FROM MYTABLE

    OPEN PCURSOR;
    WHILE EOF = 0 DO
        FETCH FROM PCURSOR INTO var_MYID;
        IF SQLCODE = 100 THEN 
            SET EOF = 1;
        ELSE
              -- nested cursor goes here
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE PCURSOR;
END
```

SQLCODE = 100 newer happens (it's always 0 when I debug). So it becomes infinite loop. I'm not using

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET EOF = 1;
```

because I'm going to use another nested cursor.

Comment: Many times you can get better results by **not** using cursors, especially nested ones.  At the moment your procedure does "nothing" (no observable result); what are you actually doing - returning a result set, updating some rows - and what do the rest of your statements look like?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse is right.  Cursors should be avoided if possible. Other than that...missing semicolon on your DECLARE CURSOR?  You should also be checking for a non-zero SQLCODE/SQLSTATE after the OPEN.

Comment: Thank you guys.. Sorry but I'm not DB2 expert.. What I need is just to do search (SELECT MYID FROM MYTABLE WHERE ....) then insert all found IDs into another table e.g. TABLE2. And in case it fails (because of unique/foreign key or existing record in TABLE2) then just update existing record in TABLE2. And Stored Procedure should return how many records where inserted and how many was updated in TABLE2. This I was going to use in nested cursor.. So let me know the best solution? I don't think trigger is good idea (e.g. trigger on record update in MYTABLE then insert/update TABLE2)

Comment: Sounds like MERGE can solve your problem.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-168

Comment: Thank you.. This is what I'm trying to do now.. MERGE is definitely better solution than CURSOR... Now just wondering why FETCH doesn't work in my example above